# Why does TypeScript not enforce interface function parameters to classes that implement this interface?

Tags: typescript

```
interface ServiceI {
  execute(req: string): string;
｝
class A implements ServiceI {
  execute() {
   return "12"
  ｝
}
```

Why this does not throw an error? `req` parameter is required on the interface however it is not enforced on the real implementation.

Comment: Your implementation satisfies the type definition. There's a duplicate for this around here somewhere...

Comment: Because you _can_ call `new A().execute("foo")`.